# How to know jedis message has been pushed or not

Tags: redis, jedis

I am using [jedis](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis) as my Java Redis Client and using `BinaryJedis` class's method for `lpush` and `rpop`. I am pushing message in a queue from `Jedis` client and there is another redis client in `nodejs` which executes blocking pop to this same queue. I am not able to get all data from this pop. I want to make sure that records are successfully pushed from `jedis` client, how can I do that with `jedis`?

Answer (score 2):

The return value from the `lpush` and `rpush` commands is the size of the list after the push is performed.  You could use a combination of the `llen` call (wrapped in a transaction to ensure correctness) to validate that the list is the right size after the push operation.